# Require help in creating design for cassandra data model for my requirement

Tags: cassandra

I have a `Job_Status` table with 3 columns:

```
Job_ID (numeric)
Job_Time (datetime)
Machine_ID (numeric)
```

Other few fields containing stats (like memory, CPU utilization)

At a regular interval (say 1 min), entries are inserted in the above table for the Jobs running on each Machines.

I want to design the data model in Cassandra.

My requirement is to get list (pair) of jobs which are running at the same time on 2 or more than 2 machines.

I have created table with `Job_Id` and `Job_Time` as *primary key* for row but in order to achieve the desired result I have to do lots of parsing of data after retrieval of records.
Which is taking a lot of time when the number of records reach around 500 thousand.
This requirement expects the operation like inner join of SQL, but I can’t use SQL due to some business reasons and also SQL query with such huge data set is also taking lots of time as I tried that with dummy data in SQL Server.

So I require your help on below points:

1. Kindly suggest some efficient data model in Cassandra for this requirement.
2. How the join operation of SQL can be achieved/implemented in Cassandra database?

Kindly suggest some alternate design/algorithm. I am stuck at this problem for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty broad question.  As a general approach you might want to look at pairing Cassandra with Spark so that you could do the large join in parallel.

You would insert jobs into your table when they start and delete them when they complete (possibly with a TTL set on insert so that jobs that don't get deleted will auto delete after some time).

When you wanted to update your pairing of jobs, you'd run a spark batch job that would load the table data into an RDD, and then do a map/reduce operation on the data, or use spark SQL to do a SQL style join.  You'd probably then write the resulting RDD back to a Cassandra table.

Comment: Thanks Jim for your response. Job deletion time is 1 year. The direction you gave me looks pretty convincing and I will explore it.